accessing members of constrained type parameters in Dafny
Dafny neophyte here (again!). Below, Scope is fine, but the 'generic' version ScopeG fails with type T does not have a member id on the line forall id :: id in id2Items ==> id == id2Items[id].id. I'd like to understand why that might be the case.
trait Identified {
  const id: string
}

trait Scope {
  const id2Items: map<string, Identified>

  predicate Valid()
    reads this
  {
    forall id :: id in id2Items ==> id == id2Items[id].id
  }
}

trait ScopeG<T extends Identified> {
  const id2Items: map<string, T>

  predicate Valid()
    reads this
  {
    forall id :: id in id2Items ==> id == id2Items[id].id
  }
}

I'm using Dafny 4.8.1.

To use a T as its bound Identified, you first have to cast it:
forall id :: id in id2Items ==> id == (id2Items[id] as Identified).id

This may change in the future to make the explicit cast unnecessary.

Using id2Items[id] as Identified gives me a type cast to reference type 'Identified' must be from an expression assignable to it (got 'T') error.

Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention. Bounded type parameters are used only by Dafny's new type system. We are working on a good moment to switch to it by default. Until then, you must explicitly use the option --type-system-refresh. (I would recommend also using --general-traits=datatype and --general-newtypes, which will be part of the new default. If you use those for your program here, you need to add extends object to the declaration of the trait. See the various release notes for more details.)

OK, that worked, thanks!
